# How can I speed up scipy.integrate.quad?

Tags: python, performance, scipy, numerical-integration

Consider the following code:

```
def disFunc(x,n):
        y = np.power(x, n-1)*np.exp(-x)
        return y
    

def disFunc2(t,n,beta):
    y = integrate.quad(disFunc, a = 0, b = beta*t, args = (n))
    return y[0]   

def disFunc3(func):
    y = np.vectorize(func)
    return(y)

maxCounter = 6000
stepSize = .001
n = 5
beta = 25
t = np.cumsum(np.ones(maxCounter)*stepSize)-stepSize
x = disFunc3(disFunc2)
start_time = time.time()
y = x(t,n,beta)
time_taken = (time.time() - start_time)
print (time_taken)
```

Works like a charm, but it is way too slow (1.85s). How can I speed it up?

Comment: Don't use `np.vectorize`.  It is no faster than a list comprehension.  As for the `quad` itself, you can't do much except makes sure `disFunc` is fast.  I don't think `quad` has turning parameters, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you just want to integrate the function you gave here:

Note that the function you wish to integrate is actually equivalent to the [Lower Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). `scipy` includes the [`scipy.special.gammainc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html) function for approximating the lower incomplete Gamma function, regularised by the (complete) Gamma function (i.e: its output is divided by Gamma(n)). We can therefore approximate the integral far more efficiently using these specialised functions:

```py
from scipy import special
import time

# ...

start_time = time.time()
y = special.gammainc(n, beta * t)
y *= special.gamma(n)  # Reverse the regularisation
time_taken = (time.time() - start_time)
print(time_taken)
print(y)
```

The time this takes will vary for different values of n, but for n = 5.5, this ran in ~0.0005 seconds on my machine, compared to 0.3 seconds for the method below.

### If you want to integrate arbitrary functions for which a closed form doesn't exist:

Here's an idea which just improves the approach you're using mathematically, rather than using JIT compilation. This runs ~10 times faster on my machine (your code takes ~2.2 seconds to run for me, this takes ~0.3 seconds):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import time


def disFunc(x, n):
    y = np.power(x, n - 1) * np.exp(-x)
    return y


def disFunc2(t_prev, t_cur, n, beta):
    y = integrate.quad(disFunc, a=beta * t_prev, b=beta * t_cur, args=(n))
    return y[0]


def disFunc3(func):
    y = np.vectorize(func)
    return y


maxCounter = 6000
stepSize = 0.001
n = 5
beta = 25
t = np.cumsum(np.ones(maxCounter) * stepSize) - stepSize
x = disFunc3(disFunc2)
start_time = time.time()
y = x(t[:-1], t[1:], n, beta)
time_taken = time.time() - start_time
print(time_taken)
print(np.cumsum(y))
```

The idea uses properties of the integral: The integral over a range [a, b] is equivalent to the integral over [a, c] plus the integral over [c, b], for some c between a and b. So, rather than calculating the integral between (0, b * t) each time, we just calculate the integral between (b * prev_t, b * t) (where prev_t is the last t we used), then run a cumulative sum. This just makes it faster because a lot less iterations of the approximation are required to carry out an integral over a smaller range.

It should be noted that this does skip the first integral (from 0 to beta * t[0]), so you might want to calculate that separately and add it to the front of the array.

Comment: Your recursive closed form is great, but I should have mentionned that n can take decimals. Is it possible to modify your integrate_by_parts function to handle cases in which n can have decimals (e.g., 5.5)?

Comment: @user1363251 Ah, unfortunately for values of n not in the natural numbers, no closed form of the integral exists in elementary functions, so it's not possible to modify the function to accomodate this, numerical integration is necessary. What I would suggest is making use of [`scipy.special.gamma`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gamma.html) to perform the approximation, rather than using the integrate module, as it is likely better optimised for this integral specifically.

Comment: Even better: The [lower incomplete gamma function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html) should be exactly what you're looking for, you just need to multiply it by the complete gamma function.

Comment: @user1363251 I've updated my answer to show how the integral can be calculated using the lower incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `np.vectorize` is often pretty slow. Perhaps you could try to change your code to not have to rely on this.

Otherwise, you could try `Numba`/`Numba-Scipy`'s jit (just in time compilation). This significantly speeds up code that uses NumPy and  Scipy:
http://numba.pydata.org/

You can then import the jit decorator, and use it on your functions:

```
from numba import jit

@jit  # or jit(nopython=False) in other scenarios
def disFunc(x,n):
        y = np.power(x, n-1)*np.exp(-x)
        return y
    
> ...
```

Make sure to install both Numba and Numba-Scipy!